# Xcode "Release-iphoneos" folder

Tags: ios, xcode, build

When I used to build an app in previous Xcode (I forgot the version, 4.earlysomething), the app got build in "Release-iphoneos" folder. Now, with new version (4.5) it builds in "Debug-iphoneos". Is it different type of executable? I presume now it has some additional debug info - how can I make it build as "release" kind, as it previously did?

Comment: Why aren't you using the archive build process to get the ipa file?

Comment: In Xcode, go to the Project menu, Manage Schemes, Edit, and double check your build configuration, Debug or Release.

Comment: @ChrisWagner: I don't know about ipa file? What is it? Is it something new?

Comment: @DanielMartín - thanks, works great. Post it below, so I can accept it.

Comment: IPA files are the prescribed way to distribute iOS apps. http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/494413

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Xcode, go to the Project menu, Manage Schemes, Edit, and double check your build configuration, Debug or Release.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply build a release by clicking in menu

**Product -> Build For -> Profiling**

You can find the results in `/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project_name>-<hash>/Build/Products/Release-*`

Comment: Great, but what if we need "Release-iphoneos" instead of "Release-iphonesimulator".